# Use regex to validate a UK National Insurance No./NINO in an HTML5 pattern attribute

Tags: regex, html, forms, validation, client-side

I'm in the middle of trying to validate a UK national Insurance no. as part of a form. Obviously it needs validating server-side as well, but I'm using the new `:valid` `:invalid` CSS pseudo-styles to give the user instant feedback on the form.

```html
<input type="text" required="required" pattern="Foo"/>
```

I'm not fluent in Regular Expressions at all. Would anyone kindly be able to solve the riddle and create a RegEx for myself and others to use inside the `pattern="#"` attribute?

If it helps, someone has already roughly answered this question before: [Regular Expression to validate UK National Insurance Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204378/regular-expression-to-validate-uk-national-insurance-number). However, upon testing, none of the answers seemed to work at all.

### A Little UK National Insurance No. Information

#### Format

The format of the number is two prefix letters, six digits, and one suffix letter.

The example typically used is `AB123456C`.

Often, the number is printed with spaces to pair off the digits, like this: `AB 12 34 56 C`.

#### Rules of the Road

- Neither of the first two letters can be
  `D`, `F`, `I`, `Q`, `U` or `V`. The second letter also cannot be `O`.
- The prefixes `BG`, `GB`, `NK`, `KN`, `TN`, `NT` and `ZZ` are not allocated.
- The suffix letter is either `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`.

Comment: Whose answer did you try from the linked question; it appears that the 'accepted' answer may not be the best one there?

Comment: All of the answers actually. I didn't find them useful. I would of marked the answers down but unfortunately I don't have the points to do so.

Comment: If you can tell me what's wrong with http://jsfiddle.net/Kmk6C/, I'll try and come up with a fix; this uses one of the RegExs from the question you mention.

Comment: Funny, this code seems to work in jsfiddle as intended, I'll try it in my build today and get back to you @adrian-wagg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^(?!BG|GB|NK|KN|TN|NT|ZZ)[A-CEGHJ-PR-TW-Z][A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z](?:\s*\d{2}){3}\s*[A-D]$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Visualization by Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ctSVO4JggVM0xm2y)

Demo:

```js
var regex = /^(?!BG|GB|NK|KN|TN|NT|ZZ)[A-CEGHJ-PR-TW-Z][A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z](?:\s*\d{2}){3}\s*[A-D]$/;
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var span = document.querySelector("span");

input.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  span.innerHTML = regex.test(event.target.value) ? "✔" : "✗";
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Ex: AB 12 34 56 D" /> <span></span>
```

Comment: Version that allows any amount of whitespace (`\s*`) between each pair of characters: `^(?!BG|GB|NK|KN|TN|NT|ZZ)[ABCEGHJ-PRSTW-Z][ABCEGHJ-NPRSTW-Z]\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*[A-D]$`

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest list provided by NEST the REGEX should be (assuming no spaces)

```
R = new Regex("

(^[AEHKLTYZ]{1}[ABEHK-MPR-TW-Z}{1}
|^[B]{1}[ABEK-MT]{1}
|^[C]{1}[ABEHKLR]{1}
|^[G]{1}[Y]{1}
|^[J]{1}[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z]{1}
|^[M]{1}[AWX]{1}
|^[N]{1}[ABEHLMPRSW-Z]{1]
|^[O]{1}[ABEHK-MPRSX]{1}
|^[P]{1}[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Y]{1}
|^[R]{1}[ABEHKMPR-TW-Z]{1}
|^[S]{1}[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z]{1}
|^[W]{1}[ABEK-MP]{1})[0-9]{6}[A-DFM]{1}$");
```

Answer (score -1):

Or try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}[A-Za-z]{1}$
```