# RegEx to validate National Insurance Number

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to use some RegEx in JS to validate a National Insurance number.

```
^(?i:[a-z-[dfiquv]])(?i:[a-z-[dfiquvo]])\d{6}(?i:a|b|c|d)$
```

This is taken from a language that is not JS, but how can I use this rule in JS?

I assume I should be escaping some characters here.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some examples of `National Insurance numbers`?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204378/regular-expression-to-validate-uk-national-insurance-number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is equivalent to this:

```
/^[abceghj-prstw-z][abceghj-nprstw-z]\d{6}[abcd]$/i
```

the original pattern doesn't work in javascript for this reason:

character class substraction is not supported by XRegExp (the javascript regex engine). So, `[a-z-[dfiquv]]` will be seen as:

```
[a-z-[dfiquv] # a character class that contains:
              #     the character range a-z
              #     -
              #     [
              #     the (duplicate) letters: dfiquv

]             # followed by a literal ]
```

An other notice about the original pattern: XRegExp doesn't support the inline modifier in a non capturing group syntax: `(?i:......)` *(that is a shortcut for `(?:(?i)......)`, note that javascript doesn't support `(?i)` too, it doesn't support inline modifiers at all)*. Since all the pattern seems to be case insensitive, the best way is to put the modifier for all the pattern like this: `/... pattern .../i` and remove the uneeded non-capturing groups.

Comment: That's what I got, by following the [Wikipedia outline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Insurance_number#Format): `/^[abceghj-prstw-z][abceghj-nprstw-z]\d{6}[a-d]$/i`

Comment: @Xophmeister: If wikipedia and you are agree with me, I will buy beers (with eucalyptus).

Comment: anyone got a pattern I can use in an <input pattern = ?

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly close to a JS compatible regex, just with minor changes try this:

```
/^(:[a-z][dfiquv])(:[a-z][dfiquvo])\d{6}(:[abcd])$/i
```

Comment: I don't think `[a-z-[dfiquv]]` is the same as `[a-z][dfiquv]`: I'm not familiar with the syntax of the former, but it looks like that class block only matches one character, whereas you have two classes, which must therefore match 2 characters... I would guess that `[a-z-[dfiquv]]` means something like `[a-z] but exclude [dfiquv]`, but I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Yes I have requested OP to provide some examples.

Comment: His profile says he's based in the UK (as am I) and "National Insurance" is a British thing. [The format is outlined on Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Insurance_number#Format)

Comment: Thanks so much let me check this Wiki page.

Comment: I believe for OP this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204378/regular-expression-to-validate-uk-national-insurance-number

Comment: anyone used this for UK NI nums in a form input pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to validate UK National Insurance numbers on a large scale and came across this post. However, I found using regex to validate was really slow. So I created this npm package which doesn't use regex and is roughly 14 x faster: [test-nino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-nino). Just thought I would share incase anyone else needs a higher performance solution.

Comment: how does it work and why is it faster? how did you run your benchmark?

Comment: I detail all this in the README.md here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-nino#benchmarks. Effectively, the package stores every possible prefix and suffix combination, and enumerates the input characters ensuring they are valid for the position they are in. Code is here: https://github.com/Tom-Hudson/test-nino/blob/master/src/validate.ts.